# Programmatically create SharePoint list

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I downloaded a plugin for an Office product that prompts you for your SharePoint site url and username and password and then it will create you appropriate lists and views on your SharePoint site. Can someone let me know if I can make a program on my Windows XP machine that will take in the site url, username and password and be able to programmatically create lists and views?

I did some searching on google and it seems this needs to be done on the SharePoint server. I don't have access to the server and would need to do the development from my XP machine. And seeing the plugin do exactly what I wanted gives me some hope.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to look at accessing SharePoint through its [Web Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms479390.aspx). Specifically, the [Lists Web Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.aspx) and the [Views Web Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/views.aspx). Here's the [Lists.AddList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.addlist.aspx) method from the lists service - should get you going down the right path.